# File recovery on external hd with Testdisk (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

I was doing some organizing on my Seagate 4 TB HDD when I attempted to cut/paste all of the movies in one directory to a new directory. I received an error message (wish I would've screenshot it, but I didn't realize something had gone wrong at this point) that said something along the lines of couldn't move this particular file because of an input/output error. There were lots of these errors queued and so I selected skip all, only to find that all of the files besides the last dozen or so alphabetically were gone from the original directory and not in the new one either. Probably about 300 or so movies gone down the drain.

I've attempted to search the HD for common file types (.mkv, .mp4, etc.), searched through the hidden trash folder, lost and found, nothing. I installed Testdisk and followed the instructions to attempt to undelete data, and while there are tens of thousands of deleted files that Testdisk detects that could be restored, none of the movies from that failed cut and paste are detected.

Not sure if anyone has dealt with a problem like this with Testdisk, but I figured I'd throw out one last desperate attempt to figure out the problem before I write anything else onto the HD and possibly lose the data forever.

Comment: First of all, a this point, **do not do any more writing to the drive at all**. Any writing can make it much more difficult to recover. Secondly, try to read the drive with a linux operating system

Comment: Agree with Eric F; don't touch the drive except to read from it.  Suggest downloading a copy of R-Studio and run it with "find the files by type" activated for video files.  It will report what is recoverable.  No, it's not free to actually use, but the price is reasonable in light of many files lost. ... When copying many large files, Microsoft Rich Copy or Roadkil's Unstoppable Copier is a better choice than cut-and-paste precisely because of this situation.